# Load a file without using a new URL() via Java

Tags: java, url, dropbox

So I am making a small game and the market that I am in is quite... competitive... So competitive that it is extremely common to have it leaked for free to the public. To leak the game, the person must remove the HWID system and the Killswitch system. To do this the most common method is just to search the entire project for "new URL" and check all of the links it makes, then remove them if needed.

This MUST only use the default Java classes, I cant use any libraries or other linkable downloads.

My question is: "Is it possible to make a request to my dropbox file to read a text document WITHOUT using the URL class?"

Not sure if I covered everything I needed to cover so if you're confused, I could provide more information if I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always implement the protocol yourself -- the bare minimum that you really need.

Answer (score 5):

This is really the age old "How do I protect my Java application from X?".

The fact is you can't. Anyone with enough time and work will be able to take apart your Java app and sew it back together. You of course can work with some great obfusacaters that make it impractical for any who wants to do it fast.

Past that point you have asked a somewhat of a trivial question. Which is "How do I hide 'new URL'". I've made the assumption that you will end up relying on the urlconnection class to actually work with the url. This could deal with a great bit of optimization and you could add more layers such as storing the class name and url as a byte array and many other things. It also could do with some caching of the constructor and class. **I really recommend you not use this!**

```
public static URLConnection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class<?> cla = Class.forName("java.net.URL");
        return (URLConnection) cla.getMethod("openConnection", new Class[0]).invoke(cla.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("http://somtopsecereturl.tld"), new Object[0]);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You of course could keep going down the stack and do the actually reading through reflection calls so you never reference the real object types making it very hard to find.

Comment: @Krroae27 The issue is that I need to load a file using this method. As I stated, I need to hide as much of the connections as possible which obfuscators just will not do. I'm unsure if the method you gave me is reliable enough to work every time but this only has to be ran at the very beginning of the launch

Comment: @user1363526 How are you loading a file now? By loading do you mean classloading? The only thing I have done here is use reflection to invoke the url class and the openconnection method so there will be no textual reference to 'new URL' (it's just as reliable as actually invoking it normally). As that is what I believed your question asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URI instead.

```
URI uri = new URI("http://...");
uri.toURL().openConnection():
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly low-tech obfuscation: create a class that contains a URL instance:

```
class myFoo {
    private URL url;
    myFoo (String s)  throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url = new URL(s);
    }
    public getHatSize() {
        return this.url;
    }
}
```